# How to speed up Script to return all files from drive

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

i use a script to take all my files from drive to a google spreadsheet with name, url...

My problem is there are a lot of files and the script run during ~30 min and exceed during time permission for apps script.

How can i speed this script please ?

```
function listFilesAndFolders() {
  var folderid = " "; // change FolderID
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(["parent","folder", "name", "update", "Size", "URL", "ID", "description", "type"]);
  try {
    var parentFolder =DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
    listFiles(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName())
    listSubFolders(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName());
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}

function listSubFolders(parentFolder,parent) {
  var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    Logger.log("Fold : " + childFolder.getName());
    listFiles(childFolder,parent)
    listSubFolders(childFolder,parent + "|" + childFolder.getName());
  }
}

function listFiles(fold,parent){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = [];
  var files = fold.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    data = [ 
      parent,
      fold.getName(),
      file.getName(),
      file.getLastUpdated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      file.getMimeType()
      ];
    sh.appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you analysed the script to see what is causing the bottleneck? Is it due to slow requests, or just weight of data?

Comment: I'm not an expert but when i have less data (~200) the script is good but now with a lot of data (~5000) the script run during a long time and exceed limit time permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then use `Sheet.appendRow()`  collect each row in an array `rows` and when all done looping use `.getRange().setValues()`.

```
function listFilesAndFolders() {
  var folderid = " "; // change FolderID
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clear();
  let rows = [["parent","folder", "name", "update", "Size", "URL", "ID", "description", "type"]];
  try {
    var parentFolder =DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
    listFiles(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName(),  rows  )
    listSubFolders(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName(),  rows  );
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}

function listSubFolders(parentFolder,parent,  rows  ) {
  var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    Logger.log("Fold : " + childFolder.getName());
    listFiles(childFolder,parent,  rows  )
    listSubFolders(childFolder,parent + "|" + childFolder.getName(),  rows  );
  }
}

function listFiles(fold,parent,  rows  ){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var files = fold.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    rows.push([ 
      parent,
      fold.getName(),
      file.getName(),
      file.getLastUpdated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      file.getMimeType()
      ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have an error @code 31 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Comment: This script works for fold who don't have subfolders with files. In my case, I have a folder with differents subfolders with files in these subfolders. My objective is return all files in each subfolders and subfolders of subfolders in one folder. I don't know if i'm clear but for resume i want return all files in one folder where there are differents subfolders

Comment: Sorry I didn't see `listFiles` in `listSubFolders`.  Simply add rows as a parameter to each as shown above.

Comment: Yea, it works in 4min vs 30min with mine ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This will list all of the files and folders in your drive into Sheet1

```
var level = 1;
function getFnF1(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  let tree = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tree));
  if (tree.level < level) {
    tree.level = level;
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  }
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  let row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level - 1) { x = folder.getName(); } else { x = ''; } return x; }));
  tree.txt.push(row);
  row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level - 1) { x = 'bold'; } else { x = 'normal'; } return x; }));
  tree.fwt.push(row);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    let row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level - 1) { x = 'Files:'; } else { x = ''; } return x; }));
    tree.txt.push(row);
    tree.fwt.push(['normal']);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  }
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let row = Array.from([...Array(level + 1).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level) { x = file.getName(); } else { x = ''; } return x; }));
    tree.txt.push(row);
    tree.fwt.push(['normal']);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    level++;
    getFnF1(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}

function getFilesAndFolders1() {
  const fldr = null;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast("Entry");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify({ txt: [], fwt: [], level: 0 }));
  getFnF1();
  //Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));
  let tree = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));
  const l = tree.level + 1
  tree.txt.forEach(r => {
    if (r.length < l) {
      //Array.from(Array(l - r.length).keys()).forEach(e => r.push(''));
      r.splice(r.length, 0, ...Array(l - r.length).fill(''));
    }
  });
  tree.fwt.forEach(r => {
    if (r.length < l) {
      //Array.from(Array(l - r.length).keys()).forEach(e => r.push('normal'));
      r.splice(r.length, 0, ...Array(l - r.length).fill('normal'));
    }
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tree));
  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.txt.length, tree.level + 1).setValues(tree.txt);
  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.fwt.length, tree.level + 1).setFontWeights(tree.fwt);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('FnF');
  ss.toast("EOF");
}
```

It takes about 3 minutes on my drive. I keep my drive pretty clean and I don't list as many parameters as you desired.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The ReferenceError: 'level is not defined' @Code.gs:4 appears when i run the code. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

### Modification points:

- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref: Author me](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- I thought that when Drive API is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification? In this modification, a Google Apps Script library is used. The author of this Google Apps Script library of [FilesApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp) is me.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

You can see how to install Google Apps Script library of [FilesApp] at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

This modified script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 3. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the top folder ID to `folderId`. If you use `var folderId = "root";`, all files in your Google Drive are retrieved.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the top folder ID.
  
  var header = ["parent", "folder", "name", "update", "Size", "URL", "ID", "description", "type"]; // This is from your script.
  var obj = FilesApp.createTree(folderId, null, "files(name,modifiedTime,size,webViewLink,id,description,mimeType)");
  var values = [header, ...obj.files.flatMap(({ folderTreeByName, filesInFolder }) => {
    const f = [folderTreeByName.join("|"), folderTreeByName.pop()];
    return filesInFolder.length == 0 ? [[...f, ...Array(7).fill(null)]] : filesInFolder.filter(({ mimeType }) => mimeType != MimeType.FOLDER).map(({ name, modifiedTime, size, webViewLink, id, description, mimeType }) => [...f, name || null, new Date(modifiedTime), size || 0, webViewLink, id, description || null, mimeType]);
  })];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

### References:

- [FilesApp of Google Apps Script library (Author me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp)
- [Files: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Thanks you for your reply and all details. I'm not autorized for activate API in my company. I will see if i can obtain autorization and try your method.

Comment: @Shironeki Thank you for replying. When you can use Drive API, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) By this, the script can be used.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, i finnaly can use API in Apps Script. I have tested your script but its don't works.. I have the error : Exceeded maximum execution time. I have installed Drive API and FilesApp in library and put my folder id in script.

Comment: @Shironeki Thank you for replying. About `I have tested your script but its don't works.. I have the error : Exceeded maximum execution time.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. But, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. So, I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I just past your script in my script editor and put my folder ID in var Folder ID. I add Drive API service and FilesApp in my library thanks to ID code 1dBxqh6gpWqFv4h0M25ALp4bhcs6CoqhiIJ0fUeUjR57bAxIN2PqfkQns. I just to do that ?

Comment: @Shironeki Thank you for replying. In your situation, how many files in your folder of `folder ID`?

Comment: Folder with ~8000 files in PDF. I have tested just with this big folder at this time. I want list all pdf files of the folder in my gsheet with name of files and URL / Link.

Comment: @Shironeki Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. But, from your reply, for example, when you modify `var obj = FilesApp.createTree(folderId, null, "files(name,modifiedTime,size,webViewLink,id,description,mimeType)");` to `var obj = FilesApp.createTree(folderId, ["application/pdf"], "files(name,modifiedTime,size,webViewLink,id,description,mimeType)");`, will the situation be changed?

Comment: It's too long... That's ok Tanaike, TheWizEd's answer above works. I still wanted to test your method with API

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for trying to solve my problem